# NodeJS AWS Lambda: Connection lost: The server closed the connection

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function deployed on AWS. This lambda function is built on top of NodeJS. This lambda function contains multiple scripts, each of which is triggered by a certain event. Lately, I have been receiving the following error, at random times, and during the execution of random scripts (I cannot find a pattern).

```
{
    "errorType": "Error",
    "errorMessage": "Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
    "code": "PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST",
    "fatal": true,
    "stack": [
        "Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.",
        "    at Protocol.end (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)",
        "    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:97:28)",
        "    at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:525:10)",
        "    at Socket.emit (events.js:203:15)",
        "    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:448:20)",
        "    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1143:12)",
        "    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)"
    ]
}
```

I did some research and found that this error is generated by MySql. However, the error occurs during the execution of scripts that do not even interact with MySQL in any way.

I have created a wrapper for MySQL in order to promisify some of its functions. Below is the code:

```
const util = require('util');

let lib = {
  'mySqlWrapper': (config) => {
    if (!config) {
      config = {
        host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
        port: process.env.MYSQL_PORT,
        user: process.env.MYSQL_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.MYSQL_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.MYSQL_DB_NAME,
        timezone: 'utc'
      }
    };
    let connection = require("mysql").createConnection(config);
    return {
      query(sql, args) {
        return util.promisify(connection.query).call(connection, sql, args);
      },
      close() {
        return util.promisify(connection.end).call(connection);
      },
      beginTransaction() {
        return util.promisify(connection.beginTransaction).call(connection);
      },
      commit() {
        return util.promisify(connection.commit).call(connection);
      },
      rollback() {
        return util.promisify(connection.rollback).call(connection);
      }
    };
  }
}

module.exports = lib;
```

Note that I am sure that every connection is created when the script is executed, and closed before the end of the script.

Moreover, I did alter a few timeouts for the database as such:

```
Name                      Value
connect_timeout             5
delayed_insert_timeout      5
lock_wait_timeout           10
wait_timeout                5
```

I do not understand the cause of this error, especially that it is happening quite randomly (Not all the time), and even during the execution of scripts that have nothing to do with MySQL. Can someone help me find the probable cause for this?